# Telegram photo format with getUserPhotos

Tags: api, telegram

I use [getUserPhotos](https://core.telegram.org/method/photos.getUserPhotos) to get profile photos. What is the main standard source that I should use for html `src` attribute? (I searched even in telegram's docs, but didn't get the solution.)

A part of my result (type is [photos.Photos](https://core.telegram.org/type/photos.Photos)):

```
Array
(
    [_] => photos.photosSlice
    [count] => 14
    [photos] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [_] => photo
                    [has_stickers] => 
                    [id] => 195744071274310414
                    [access_hash] => -5116812755800708610
                    [date] => 1472714208
                    [sizes] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [_] => photoSize
                                    [type] => a
                                    [location] => Array
                                        (
                                            [_] => fileLocation
                                            [dc_id] => 4
                                            [volume_id] => 425426808
                                            [local_id] => 100105
                                            [secret] => -7781982930425156181
                                        )

                                    [w] => 160
                                    [h] => 160
                                    [size] => 11694
                                )
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is use the following method to download your file or picture:

```
upload.getFile#e3a6cfb5 location:InputFileLocation offset:int limit:int = upload.File;
```

Where `InputFileLocation` is defined below, and may be obtained from  `PhotoSize.location` in your question above:

`inputFileLocation#14637196 volume_id:long local_id:int secret:long = InputFileLocation;`

more details on file download here: https://core.telegram.org/api/files#downloading-files

Comment: Thank you. And one more thing that I can't understand about telegram api. What is `#e3a6cfb5` after the method name?

Comment: That is the TL method or Object identifier tag.